# Remove hover from Magento menu

Tags: magento, menu, hover, categories

How can I remove hover from categories menu in Magento? I want to display categories on click.
I tried something like this:

```
jQuery('#nav ul li a').removeClass('over');
jQuery('#nav ul li a').removeClass('level-top over');
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The `onhover` event is defined in `/js/varien/menu.js`. You can start from there.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't know why my jQuery doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "shown-sub" class displays the sub-menus on the default Magento menu.

**EDIT:**

This is a dirty solution but it works. See http://sami.seoresearch.com/

What I did was to edit: /js/varien/menu.js

Line 58 - Remove the mousein/mouseout events and replace with:

```
 list.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    main.fireNavEvent(this,true);
 };
```

Line 78 - Change it to:

```
if(!elm.hasClassName("over")){
```

Also, you could see the source js file here: http://sami.seoresearch.com/js/varien/menu.js

Comment: I know, but using jQuery to display shown-sub class doesn't work. Magento displays it only on hover and I don't know what to do to display all subcategories always, not only on hover.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I was wandering is there any way to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
jQuery('#nav ul li a').hover(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but it doesn't work. I also cannot find where display categories on hover is defined.

Comment: do u have some online link to your page?

Comment: Not yet. I'm doing it on Magento community edition at this moment

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem:

```
jQuery("#nav li>a.level-top").on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

jQuery("#nav li>a.level-top").on('mouseout', function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#nav li > a.level-top, #nav li ul li, #nav li ul li a").on('mouseover', function(event){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

        jQuery("#nav li > a.level-top, #nav li ul li, #nav li ul li a").on('mouseout', function(event){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
        jQuery('#nav > li > a').removeAttr('href');
        jQuery('#nav > li > a').click(function(e){
            jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('over');
            jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').toggleClass('shown-sub');
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```